# How to import everything from the crate root?

Tags: rust

To import symbols from a module you either need to enumerate them or use a wildcard to import everything. That is, I can use either `use module::{SomeSymbol, SomeOtherSymbol};` or `use module::*;`

However, when importing from the top-level module, the crate root, wildcards don't work. I can use either `use {SomeSymbol, SomeOtherSymbol};` or `use ::{SomeSymbol, SomeOtherSymbol}};` but neither `use *;` nor `use ::*;` work.

Why doesn't it work and how to import everything from the crate root?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of Rust 1.14, **`use *;` and `use ::*;` now work as intended** (importing everything from the crate root)**!**

---

Useful links:

- [PR that introduced the syntax](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/37367)
- [Old issue about the lack of said syntax](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31484)
- [My old answer in the edit log](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41191746/1)

Comment: I think glob imports are used far too often for this text to be correct.

Comment: @bluss they may be used often, but I feel they are used in specific narrow conditions - importing a module for unit tests (we only want the most recent ancestor), importing a prelude (we create a specific container that means "all of these should be imported"), or all the variations of an enum (which is usually constrained to a function's context). Personally, I'm always a bit wary when encountering a glob import.